# Docker-compose: How can I add a volume to a NodeJS source-code directory?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a NodeJS application running on a Compose service and would like to access its source-code directory from outside via volumes. I tried to do that like this:

```
volumes:
  - "./source_code:/myApplication"
```

Still, when I run `nodemon index.js` all I get is nodemon trying to run on an empty folder, with the following error message:

```
Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]
See "nodemon --help" for more
```

I have searched around, but found no similar problems from other people. Is there a problem with the way I'm defining that volume? How would it be done properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with your `Dockerfile`, the volume declaration is fine I think. See below and compare with your setup.  All my files are in the same directory

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  node-mon:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # read only volume to current directory
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/app-dir:ro
```

Dockerfile to listen on the app.js file

```
#Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app-dir
RUN npm install -g nodemon
WORKDIR /opt/app-dir
CMD nodemon app.js
```

app.js file with a console log

```
# app.js
console.log('it works!')
```

Comment: I have a similar Dockerfile, except for I haven't explicitly created the folder I intended to mount as a volume using `mkdir`, trusting `COPY` would create it. I have now tried it like your file, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help anyway.